# Chrome Extension script console is not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Simply I have this script that get current window opened tabs , Actually the code is so simple:

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win)
{
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(win.id, function(tabs)
    {
        // Should output an array of tab objects to your dev console.
        console.log(tabs);
    });
});
```

when using `alert()` instead of `console.log()` , it works well and alerts tabs as objects , but when using `console.log()` , nothing shows up , not even error.

the script is launched when i click the extension button.

Comment: i don't have any details about your extension, but these logs will show up in the console where you run this code. for example if this code is part of a background script then you should inspect it and check the console there. the same applies for a popup.

Comment: @keune Excuse me , but please explain how can i inspect a script ?? usually i inspect the window that is currently opened.

Comment: on the extensions page, where your extension is. of course if you have a background page. http://imgur.com/pQOvzfJ . if you click it another window will open with a different console. same thing happens when you right click your extension's icon and choose 'Inspect popup'. Another console with different context. That is why i said if the code is run from one of these contexts, you won't see their logs in current tab's console.

Comment: @keune ahh this is the problem , i dont have the inspect link there !! http://imgur.com/Lqzfve6

Comment: @keune oh nvm i found he solution , right clicking the extension button shows a new popup with the script console , thank you.

Comment: Not an answer, but you should simplify your code to `chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, callback);` The code you are using is very old and those functions are deprecated.

Comment: @Xan if you add this as answer iw ould accept it :) thanks.